# How to do Integration Test create through other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing

1) I have this model Job and the model institution

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :institution
  # others attibutes
end
```

2) This is my action create on JobsController - I need a institution to create a job. it is fine.

```
def create
    build_job
    save_job || render(:new, status: :unprocessable_entity)
end
```

3) This is the integration test that I created
I am not getting the success test

In **params**

`-I also tried  institution: @institution
-and also tried institution_id: @institution.id`

```
require 'test_helper'

class JobActionsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = users(:standard)
    sign_in @user
    @institution = institutions(:standard)
  end

  test "can create a job through institution" do
    get new_institution_job_path(@institution)
    assert_response :success

    assert_difference('Job.count') do
      post jobs_path, 
           params: {job: {title: "Desenvolvedor", description: "Ruby",
                          requirements: "rspec and capybara", 
                          start_date: Date.today, 
                          end_date: Date.today + 5.days, 
                          institution: @institution.id}}
    end

    assert_response :redirect
    follow_redirect!
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

4) And this is my console error

```
#Running:
E

Error:
JobActionsTest#test_can_create_a_job_through_institution:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Institution with 'id'=
    app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:74:in `job_scope'
    app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:52:in `build_job'
    app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:18:in `create'
    test/integration/job_actions_test.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <class:JobActionsTest>'
    test/integration/job_actions_test.rb:21:in `block in <class:JobActionsTest>'


bin/rails test test/integration/job_actions_test.rb:17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by nesting the `jobs` resource properly:

```
resources :institutions do
  resources :jobs, only: [:new, :create]
end

# or to create the full suite
resources :institutions do
  resources :jobs, shallow: true
end
```

This will give these routes:

```
             Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                      Controller#Action
   institution_jobs POST /institutions/:institution_id/jobs(.:format)     jobs#create
new_institution_job GET  /institutions/:institution_id/jobs/new(.:format) jobs#new
...
```

Note that `:institution_id` is a now a part of URI pattern for the create route, and it will be available as `params[:institution_id]`.

In your test you want to POST to `/institutions/:institution_id/jobs`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class JobActionsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = users(:standard)
    sign_in @user
    @institution = institutions(:standard)
  end

  # Use separate examples per route / case
  test "can fill in form to create a new job" do
     get new_institution_job_path(@institution)
     assert_response :success
  end

  test "can create a job through institution" do
    assert_difference ->{ @institution.jobs.count } do
      post institution_jobs_path(@institution), 
           params: { 
             job: {
               title: "Desenvolvedor", 
               description: "Ruby",
               requirements: "rspec and capybara", 
               start_date: Date.today, 
               end_date: Date.today + 5.days
             }
           }
    end
    assert_redirected_to @institution.jobs.last
    follow_redirect!
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

Further you want to test that the job actually was created for the right institution. We do that by passing the lambda `->{ @institution.jobs.count }`.

And that the users are redirected to the correct resource - not just somewhere - which is done with `assert_redirected_to @institution.jobs.last`.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked for me. Your tips about how to put the correct route and how to create the job for the right institution helped me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that when you call at line 22

```
get new_institution_job_path(@institution)
```

the `@institution` object you have built in the `setup` block is not saved in the database.

The error you are receiving, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`, says that it cannot be found an Institution with id `nil`.

You can easily check if I am guessing correctly by adding this assertion:

```
  test "can create a job through institution" do
    assert_not_nil(@institution.id) # or assert_not_equal(0, Institution.where(id: @institution.id).size)
    get new_institution_job_path(@institution)
    assert_response :success
    #...
  end
```

Make sure that your `institutions(:standard)` method looks like `Institution.create!()` and not like `Institution.new` or `Institution.build`

Comment: Are you sure about that? `institutions(:standard)` looks like he is accessing [a fixture](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures). They are created in the DB before every test run.

Comment: I am not 100% sure since my test suite usually is `rspec` and I use `factory_girl` for fixtures. However, the error message the OP is getting is RecordNotFound, so I assume that during the test he cannot find a record with nil id (according to the traceback). I agree that `@institution` is an ActiveRecord instance, but I guess it is not saved in the DB. Maybe it would be worth to try `@institution.save!` in the setup block

Comment: Actually the lines `get new_institution_job_path(@institution); assert_response :success` are passing which should mean that the record is persisted. But its hard to tell since everybody writes integration tests in minitest like a madmans ranting.